# trails trying to build a menu, need some assistance on the polymorphic association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to build a menu for a CMS and in it, you have top level sections (determined by not belonging to another section) that has a list of either more sections or navigation_items.

I'm having trouble getting it all connected.

I have the following models:

section.rb:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section, polymorphic: true
  has_many :navigation_items
end
```

navigation_item.rb:

```
class NavigationItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
end
```

Could I please get some help getting it all connected as I expect it to work?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `I'm having trouble getting it all connected`. 
I thought it was self evident.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured it out,

I needed to do a migration that would do:

```
def change
    change_table :sections do |t|
      t.references :items, polymorphic: true, index: true, on_delete: :nullify, on_update: :cascade
      t.references :section, index: true, on_delete: :nullify, on_update: :cascade
    end
end
```

and then for the classes do:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :items, polymorphic: true
  has_many :navigation_items, as: :items
  has_many :sections, as: :items
end

class NavigationItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :items, polymorphic: true
end
```